# _asm int 5H, can use visual studio to excute this instruction?

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, interrupt-handling

_asm int 5h usually work as prtscrn. how can check this one. not only prntscrn any interrupt like reboot int 19h.. etc. can interrupt through application.
I tried to code for reboot

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //_asm mov al, 2
    _asm int 19h //reboot
    //_asm in 3
}
```

its giving access violation

Comment: I *really* doubt you can access any of those interrupts from user code nowadays (except int 80 for syscalls)...

Comment: Then how can i do this things, I need to write kernel code. like drivers.

Comment: OK, then you get the WinDDK and use those APIs to write driver code.

Comment: :) thats huge task right now. so there is no way to check from application. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of the BIOS or MSDOS interrupts (int 0x10 through 0x33 and a few rarely used ones with bigger numbers) will work in a Windows application. They can only work in DOS programs. Windows provides its functionality for Windows apps using different methods and all these BIOS/DOS ints are not supported in Windows apps. In Windows apps they cause an exception, and typically result in a termination of your program by the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking these interrupts are protected (assuming you're not running in real mode DOS). Perhaps int 5h *might* work because it was the interrupt for having pressed print screen key.

Comment: That means ring 0, ring 1 may be having priviliges to run execute INT. Appplications need to use some other system serivecs to execute INT right ? I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, technically ring 3 is being prohibited from running INT. Then the O/S catches all INT instructions and decides which are valid and which aren't.